# WebApi and Controller overkill

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm starting to integrate WebApi & OData into a test bed application. Let's keep it simple and stick with one domain entity, Customer. Obviously I will have an MVC controller. Searching gets it own view model (based on a Lucene index), so that will be separate controller, right now ODataController. But since the view/edit pages will have their own view models, they'd be their own controller. This starts to feel like overkill.

Trying to figure out a good design to make this work and still work with the idea of the URL representing the entity. Should the entity in the URL be Customer and somehow I provide different representations based on URL params? Or should Customer/CustomerSearch/CustomerEdit be different entities (which doesn't sound right)?

Comment: Rich, I'm currently working on a project where we intend to use OData and Web API, but I want to make it flexible (likee EF calls). We're not at that stage (intend to move from direct db to services). You are on thinking ahead of the curve. That's why I don't think there is anyone to help you. OData is not new anymore but I don't think many shops are using it yet. The marriage with web API seemed intuitively obvious to me so I did a research. here are some videos on implementing such a solution from our frnds at MS http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming that this WebAPI application is going to be a separate solution from the ASP.NET MVC solution you are going to build. In a nutshell, the WebAPI will be the business/domain layer and the MVC will be the presentation layer.

So, in speaking of the WebAPI solution, you only need a single `ApiController` for the Customer example you presented above. The view/edit request may have their own view models...or not. Depending on how you craft the view model, you may be able to have a single view model for customers, or you could develop a customer view hierarchy where the base view model holds the search-related data and the descendant view model fleshes out the details.

Your routing requests could look like:

```
GET - /Customer/                  retrieve multiple customers 
                                  (supplying OData parameters in query string)
GET - /Customer/{id}              retrieve a single customer
PUT - /Customer/{id}              edit customer
```

What it looks like is you will need is two routes, one `ApiController` for Customer, and three request methods for what you described. I don't recommend a separate `ApiController` for OData, because the functionality is dependent on a entity.

Comment: After thinking about it, I'm definitely looking at not using ODataController, especially only Gets will be done, and because it locks me down into the controller only working for one entity type. I'm using a variation of this routing. "/Customer" using the WebApi base Queryable functionality for search and actions for View model and Edit model "/Customer/View/{id}" + "/Customer/Edit/{id}"

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your approach. You're going to use actions on the WebAPI side, rather than the HTTP verbs?

Comment: Probably need both. The issue is that the model for a view only and a model for an edit are going to be by definition different. For example, a edit model might need a list of possible Roles the customer could have. The view model obviously won't have that. But the edit model will need both GET and PUT/POST.

Comment: O.K. So you're using MVVM-style view models. I typically use controllers, repositories and POCOs, and stick to the MVC strategy. Just personal preferences...code what's comfortable, I always say.